# admin_menu Drupal

Tags: php, cms, drupal

Ранее не работал с Drupal, сейчас выпала не большая задача с сайтом на нем, захожу я в админку,а панель управления нет. Как оптимально можно решить этот вопрос? Пробовал скачивать admin_menu, заливал все файлы в папку сайта admin-menu, но что-то не помогло, благодарен любому совету.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй набрать этот адрес [http://адрес-сайта/admin/modules](http://%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/admin/modules) и посмотреть чтоб был включен модуль "Menu"